# std::bind argument copying behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

Is it safe to pass an `std::shared_ptr` to `std::bind` when the function object will be called asynchronously?

I.E. Is roughly the following safe:

```
// Copy do not reference shared_ptr
void someFunc(std::shared_ptr<Something> arg1,...other args...);

std::shared_ptr<Something> data; // This may go out of scope before the functor below is called
auto myFuture = QtConcurrent::run(std::bind(&someFunc,data,...other args...)); // In this case using QT but could be anything else
```

I'm thinking that as `std::bind` takes its arguments by reference and the above will not be safe but want to confirm.

For the record I'm using two compilers:

1. clang 7 (OS X)
2. VC++ 12.0 (I.E. Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: Why does it matter how `std::bind` takes its arguments? Surely what matters is whether it puts a copy of them into the thing it returns rather than how it takes them.

Comment: Good point. That was poor wording on my behalf. What I was concerned about is whether a copy or reference is kept by the returned functor, which T.C. has answered nicely below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function object returned by `std::bind` stores copies of the bound arguments, so your code is safe as far as lifetime of `data` is concerned.